# Multiplying three models in django and getting the result in views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My model:

```
class VisData(models.Model):
visdata_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,blank=True)
user_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
buy_sell = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True,blank=True)
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False,null=True,editable=True,blank=True)
hour = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,null=True,editable=True,blank=True)
shares_number = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0,default=0,max_digits=999,null=True,blank=True)
course = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,default=0,max_digits=999,null=True,blank=True)
fare = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,default=0,max_digits=999,null=True,blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I want to assign:

```
total_value = (shares_number * (course - fare)) and just print it in terminal
```

My views:

```
def summaryPage(request):
visdata = VisData.objects.all()
#print(visdata)

context = {}
return render(request, 'smth/homepage.html', context)
```

I found some close answers but I couldn't understand the solution nor use them in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably need called [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/):

```py
from django.db.models import F, Sum


def summaryPage(request):
    aggregated_data = VisData.objects.annotate(
       intermid_result=F('course') - F('fare')
    ).annotate(
       record_total=F('shares_number') * F('intermid_result')
    ).aggregate(
       total=SUM('record_total')
    )
    result = aggregated_data['total']
    print(result)
    ...
```

This query will annotate each record with the value of `record_total = shares_number * (course - fare)` and then calculate a sum  for `record_total` of all records.

Also try to avoid using camelcase function names in Python. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for details.

Comment: Thank you for an answer but this doesn't solve my issue, I want to calculate them and then sum up, not the other way because:
When there are 2 models with those values:
10 * 5 - 2  = 30
5 * 3 - 1  = 10

They should give 40 overall, but when you sum the values it gives 15 * 4 = 75

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the idea. I made changes to my answer - please check if that fits your needs now.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly and I will try to avoid camelcase. :)